# converting a html/css template into asp.net mvc 4

Tags: c#, html, css, asp.net-mvc, asp.net-mvc-4

I want to integrate a html/css template that I designed into an asp.net mvc 4 project. I tried  to change the _layout.cshtml but there still problems. I am a beginner in asp mvc. Is there any tutorial that can help. 
I found a tutorial that deals with mvc 3 , it is not the saùe as mvc 4 
thanks

Comment: There are tons of tutorials.  Here is a good place to start:  http://www.asp.net/mvc/tutorials

Comment: take a look at [http://www.asp.net/mvc](http://www.asp.net/mvc) here you will find tutorials

Answer (score 1):

May I recommend not only looking at the MVC 4 specific tutorials, but also just looking at the layout.cshtml that comes with MVC and reverse engineering it.  Notice all the files that it pulls in, and try to pull those in to your custom HTML file.

Ref.  http://www.asp.net/mvc/tutorials/mvc-4/getting-started-with-aspnet-mvc4/intro-to-aspnet-mvc-4